# Can Netbeans configured to fix imports, using *, to decrease code lines

Tags: java, import, netbeans

I know that with **Ctrl + Shift + I**, one can fix imports easily in Netbeans.

Can Netbeans configured in a way that

- rather than importing **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML**,
- it will import **com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.***.

Hence, my code lines will be decreased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to **Tools > Options > Editor > Formatting**, then select **Language: Java** and **Category: Imports**. Finally, select the option **Use Package Imports**, and then click **Apply**:

[image: importStyle]

Be aware that this configuration change will affect all of your projects; I don't think it can be set at the project level. Also, note that while the approach you are choosing certainly may reduce the number of lines in your source, it is more usual to have a separate import for each class.